# Failed to run python script from batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a python script from a windows batch file.

My batch file is

```
@echo OFF

python C:\work\a.py
```

it works for me. But when I do it like this

```
@echo OFF

set fi = C:\work\a.py
python %fi%
```

it opens the python console.

Comment: That is not the proper syntax for the `SET` command.  Open up a command prompt and type: `set /?` to read the usage.  It does not show any spaces before or after the equals symbol.

Comment: You have created the variable `%fi<space>%`, with the value `<space>C:\work\a.py`! You should use, `Set "fi=C:\work\a.py"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386697/why-is-no-string-output-with-echo-var-after-using-set-var-text-on-comman)